# please help me << Can't open Android Studio - 'tools.jar' seems to be not in Studio classpath

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

When I open Android Studio, I get this error:

> 'tools.jar' seems to be not in Studio classpath.
>
> Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Does your JAVA_HOME points to existing jdk and system PATH contains path to jdk binary folder?

Answer (score 0):

Install java **jdk** and [add it to PATH](https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml).